# Pass external component as property in Angular2+

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Suppose there is a component ButtonComponent and SideComponent. How to pass 'ButtonComponent' as a property to 'SideComponent'?

For eg,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-btn',
  template: '<span>My button</span>'
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

} 


@Component({
  selector: 'my-side',
  template: '<div><div class="btn-section">{{myBtn}}</div><div class="content-section"><ng-content></ng-content></div></div>'
})
export class SideComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() myBtn:any = null;
}

Usage:
<my-side [myBtn]="btnTmpl">
  Hello, this is my content
</my-side>
<my-btn #btnTmpl></my-btn>
```

But this doesn't work, final template shows [Object Object] as output.

Comment: You don't pass components to other components. Whatever you actually want to do, this is not the proper solution. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: you are just passing template ref

Comment: @JBNizet: I need to create a placeholder inside SideComponent so that any type of data passed from user should be visible there. It is similar to how React allows to pass any component as props to another component.

Comment: So you want content projection, as explained in Todd Palmer's answer.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to use `ng-content`. ng-content is a way to display dynamic HTML in your component.

Todd Motto has a good writeup here:
https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

So your code would look something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-btn',
  template: '<span>My button</span>'
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

} 


@Component({
  selector: 'my-side',
  template: '<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class SideComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

Usage then looks like this:

```
<my-side>
  <my-btn></my-btn>
</my-side>
```

Comment: In this approach whatever I pass inside <my-side> will be replaced inside <ng-content>, I don't want to do this. I just want to show specific content at that place.

Comment: @Nitesh The *specific content* is what you decide to pass inside the <my-side> component body. If you want something specific, pass something specific. You really need to clarify what you mean if you want more help.

Comment: @JBNizet: I modified my code, please check if it makes sense otherwise I'll explain more.

Comment: @Nitesh Don't modify your code. Explain what you want to achieve. With words. Code that doesn't work won't help us figure out what you want to do.

Comment: ok, 
there are 2 div sections inside my-side component.
Inside first div, ng-content is there so anything user has put inside <my-side> component will be replaced there.
Inside 2nd div, user can either show any other angular component or simply some other html element. For this, I am accepting input from user as a property of <my-side> component. How to do this?

Comment: Use content projection, but with two ng-content. See https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content#multi-slot-content-projection for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-template

**app.component.html**

```
<my-side>
  <ng-template>
      <my-btn></my-btn> 
  </ng-template>
</my-side>
```

**ts**

```
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template:TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.template);
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-parent